# RTSP using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp, rtsp-client, openrtsp

I wanted to stream a video file from one computer to another using FFmPEG. What I tried is:

- RTSP server from here: https://github.com/revmischa/rtsp-server
- transmitted a video file a1.mp4 using ffmpeg with the following command:

> ffmpeg -re -i a1.mp4 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1
> rtsp://192.168.0.xxx:5545/abc

- Played the video using VLC player.

  ```
  vlc  rtsp://192.168.0.xxx/abc
  ```

It works fine when I run the player in the same computer. But fails to stream into the VLC player of another computer in the network.

```
 vlc  rtsp://192.168.0.xxx/abc
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the errors and also confirm the computers can reach each other for other traffic - e..g you van ping from one to the other.

Comment: If you don't specify the RTSP port in the vlc URL, it will default to 554. So your vlc URL should have :5545 after the IP address. If your computer has a firewall enabled, you may need to open port 5545 for UDP and/or TCP.